# In components.1.components.0.emoji.id: Invalid emoji - But the emojis exist

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, discord-buttons

My discord bot is giving this error:

(I'm brazilian, so ignore the variables in Portuguese)

```
2023-06-01 21:40:39 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
2023-06-01 21:40:41 INFO     discord.gateway Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: 1465193255925ba1091b52b72b22ee28).
Entrei no servidor como Code Bot#1037.
2023-06-01 21:40:44 ERROR    discord.client Ignoring exception in on_ready
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/phgodoycosta/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 441, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/phgodoycosta/OneDrive/Code_Company/bots/code_bot/bot.py", line 33, in on_ready
    await Methods.init(pessoa)
  File "/home/phgodoycosta/OneDrive/Code_Company/bots/code_bot/methods.py", line 89, in init
    await Methods.startCallbackCargosLinguagens(client)
  File "/home/phgodoycosta/OneDrive/Code_Company/bots/code_bot/methods.py", line 255, in startCallbackCargosLinguagens
    await message.edit(view=view)
  File "/home/phgodoycosta/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/message.py", line 2178, in edit
    data = await self._state.http.edit_message(self.channel.id, self.id, params=params)
  File "/home/phgodoycosta/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 744, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In components.1.components.0.emoji.id: Invalid emoji
```

This is a partial code of the main file: (bot.py)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands as c
from conn_db import Connection
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
import asyncio
#from commandos import Comandos
from random import randint
from utils import Utils
from questionary import Questionary
from verifications import Verifications
from commandos import bot as pessoa
from methods import Methods

load_dotenv()
connector = Connection()
utils = Utils(pessoa=pessoa)
questionary = Questionary()
verification = Verifications(pessoa=pessoa)

@pessoa.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Entrei no servidor como {pessoa.user}.")
    await pessoa.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("/help"))
    guild = pessoa.get_guild(int(os.environ["CODE_COMPANY_ID"]))
    adm = guild.get_member(int(os.environ["ADM_ID"]))
    await Methods.init(pessoa)
```

And the problem is with Methods.init()

The partial file: (methods.py)

```py
import discord
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from conn_db import Connection
from utils import Utils

load_dotenv()

class Methods:
   @classmethod
    async def startCallbackCargosLinguagens(cls, client):
        guild = client.get_guild(int(os.environ["CODE_COMPANY_ID"]))
        channel = guild.get_channel(int(os.environ["CARGOS_CHANNEL"]))
        message = await channel.fetch_message(int(os.environ["LINGUAGENS_MESSAGE"]))
        
        view = discord.ui.View.from_message(message)
        view.timeout = None
       
        #there was a process in View, but I commented it and the error persisted

        await message.edit(view=view)
```

I created a message with buttons on my Discord server where everyone can click on their favorite programming language and receive a corresponding role. However, I'm encountering an issue with the function that edits the message when I shut down the bot.

So I checked every emoji used on message and confirmed that the error persists

I'm using discord==>2.2.3 and Python 3.10.6

The bot has admin permissions, for test the emojis, I use this code:

```py
guild = pessoa.get_guild(int(os.environ["CODE_COMPANY_ID"]))
chat = guild.get_channel(int(os.environ["COMMAND_CHANNEL"]))

e = ""
for emoji in guild.emojis:
    e += str(emoji) + " "
    
await chat.send(e)
```

And it sended every emoji of server.

I try execute the code out of `on_ready()` but some important variables were not loading. And call the `wait_until_ready` (in and out of on_ready). The error persists

Comment: **Never** do things in the `on_ready` event. Try to achieve things differently and see if the error still occurs.

Comment: Does your bot have access to that emoji? (i.e. is in the server the emoji is from) If it does, it might try to do this before it is logged in "properly" since you do this logic in the `on_ready` function. Maybe try a `wait_until_ready` call? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=wait%20until%20ready#discord.ext.commands.Bot.wait_until_ready But I agree with the commenter above that you should probably try to achieve your goal differently

Comment: Hi, I tried your suggestions but to no avail :(
I edited the question with more details

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem.

The discord change the ID of one of emojis in the message. So I send the message again with the bot using `discord.utils.get()`